# Does で goes with 備わる here?

Tags: grammar, parsing

From the beginning of the first book of 魔法科高校の劣等生 (その refers to 魔法)

> 当初、その異能は「超能力」と呼ばれていた。**純粋に先天的な、突然変異で備わる能力であって**、共有・普及可能な技術体系化は不可能と考えられていた。

I might be overthinking but I'm not sure about で after 突然変異. I wonder if「先天的な、突然変異で」is actually modifying 備わる because when I look up this word in a monolingual dictionary, I noticed が is typically used like「冷暖房の備わった部屋」for example. How will the meaning change if「先天的な、突然変異の備わる」is used?

Or maybe, the first part of the sentence is parsed like this way

> 純粋に (先天的な、突然変異**で**) (備わる能力**で**) あって

Both で goes to あって. I'm not sure if that's case because I think でも should be used instead of で.

Comment: If you're feeling 備わる is a tricky intransitive verb, thinking of it as "to come/exist (as an equipment or to enhance something)" is not too far. 彼には才能がある = 彼には才能が備わっている = "Talent exists around him"; 冷暖房の備わった部屋 = 冷暖房が備わった部屋 = "a room where an air conditioner has come"; 突然変異**で**備わる能力 = "an ability that comes *by/through* mutation".

Comment: `純粋に (先天的な、突然変異で) (備わる能力で) あって` ← いや。。  How about parsing it like 「（純粋に先天的な）、（突然変異で備わる）能力であって」? 　「純粋に先天的な」 and 「突然変異で備わる」 both modify 能力.

Answer (score 2):

That last であって is just [である](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/74286/language-rules-of-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B-beyond-simply-replacing-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-%E3%81%A0) in the continuative て form and it acts more or less like です. With this in mind, we can safely assume that the sentence is parsed like this:

> (純粋に先天的な、突然変異で備わる**能力**)である
>
> It's purely an innate ability obtained by mutation.

In that previous sentence, the が is implicit and goes with 能力. The mutation 突然変異 is the means/method by which that ability is acquired, so it needs で. If you change it to 突然変異の備わる能力, this would mean that the ability itself "possess" a mutation (I'm unsure if 備わる can even be used like that in the first place). Assuming we're talking about humans, an example with が for the same context would be:

> その能力の備わる人間 [...]